How to receive frame sent from balast using rx in dali protocol in arduino
I'm using this circuit

DALI RX is linked to an arduino.
I'm able to to see the frame using the oscilloscope.
I tried some codes but they didn't work.
void loop() {
  TRAM[0] = a;
  //delayMicroseconds(416.5/2); // Peut être nécessaire pour la synchronisation

  int etat1 = a;
  int etat2 = a;
  for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++) {
    while (etat1 == etat2) {
      etat2 = digitalRead(Rx);
    }
    TRAM[i] = etat2;
    etat1 = etat2;
    Serial.print(TRAM[i]);
  }
  
  Serial.print("/");
  for (int i = 0; i < 18; i += 2) {
    if (TRAM[i] == 0 && TRAM[i + 1] == 1) {
      response[i] = 0; // Assurez-vous que `response` est correctement défini ailleurs
    } else if (TRAM[i] == 1 && TRAM[i + 1] == 0) {
      response[i] = 1;
    }
  }`

But it didn't work.
Can somebody suggest a code?

ouss bk - Hi, Where did that image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + PDF title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. a book), there is more detail in that site rule. Always reference to the best of your ability. TY (Please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules.)

But it didn't work ... what does that mean? ... what did happen?

Please describe which results you expect, which you see, and how you analyse them. A Serial.print() inside a high speed receiver loop is not a good idea. What is "a" initially?

In addition to the timing problem introduced by the Serial print within the receive loop, you're expecting 18 changes of line state, but a DALI backward frame can be anything from 10 to 18 changes depending on the data. Also your code isn't checking the stop condition correctly so you would detect the first 18 changes of a forward frame as a backward frame.
Here's a diagram showing frames with the most and least changes


thanks bro, can u give me a working code for this case ?
